# How can I execute a java program without a main method with VSCode?

Tags: java, maven, junit, visual-studio-code, selenide

I want to debug a java program without a main method using selenide tools. I can run the program from command line without any problem but when I try to debug it with VSCode, it outputs

**The file 'Weather.java' is not executable. Please select a main class you want to run.**

Is there any way to debug my program without using a main method?"

**Weather.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;
// import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.*;
// import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selectors.*;
import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner;
// import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvFileSource;


class Weather {
  @ParameterizedTest
  @CsvFileSource(resources = "Weather.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
  void openWeather(String ward) {
    String area = System.getProperty("area");

    Configuration.browser = WebDriverRunner.CHROME;
    // Configuration.headless = true;

    // Googleトップページ
    open("https://www.google.co.jp/");

    // "天気"を検索
    $("input[type=text]").val("天気").pressEnter();

    // Youtube検索ページへ飛ぶ
    $x("//a[@href='https://weather.yahoo.co.jp/weather/jp/13/4410/13120.html']").click();

    $("#searchText").setValue(area);
    $("#yjw_button_search").click();
    $x("//a[text()= '" + ward + "']").click();

  }
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "java",
      "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
      "request": "launch",
      "mainClass": "${file}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Run Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run Test",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "mvn test -Dtest=Weather -Darea=\"東京\"",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Current versions are as follows:

- selenide:5.5.2
- VSCode:1.41.0
- junit:5.3.2
- Apache Maven:3.6.0

Comment: Did you configure a debugger for Java in VS Code? If you have not, then you can do from here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug

Comment: @nagendra547 Thank you for your message. I've already installed that extension. But It didin't work.

Answer (score 0):

Run tests with the Java extensions for Visual Studio Code was to simply click on the Explorer (file) icon, then expand the **Test Explorer** option, explore down to whatever test(s) you want to run, right-click, and then choose your testing options. There is no need to use the `launch.json file` to do this.

Comment: I need to use launch.json because I pass variable in the command line. The run command is as follows.


 **mvn test -Dtest=Weather -Darea="東京"** The "area" is variable that I pass to run program. The reason I want to run test at debug mode is because I want test to stop at any breakpoints.

Comment: maybe you could look at [this](https://gist.github.com/felixfbecker/1b03770e83bf795ebde8)